# Unexplained browser scroll bar when using javascript code inside <div> set to overflow-y:scroll;

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I have a webpage that has one `<div>` with `overflow-y:scroll;` and for some reason my webpage is showing a vertical scroll bar. When I scroll down the page it's just blank, but it appears to be compensating for the div content because when I scroll to the bottom of the div, the webpage scroll bar disappears.

CSS:

```css
#wrapper {width:1227px; height:400px; overflow-y:scroll;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<script>
    // Create the datePicker
    datePickerController.createDatePicker({ 
    // Associate the three text inputs to their date parts                         
    formElements:{\"" . $emp_query['Emp_ID'] . "\":\"%Y-%m-%d\"},
    // Disable the fade effect
    noFadeEffect:true,
    // Show week numbers
    showWeeks:false,
    // Set a statusbar format
    statusFormat:\"%l, %d%S %F %Y\",
    //Highlight Certain days
    highlightDays:[0,0,0,0,0,1,1],
    });
    </script>
</td>
</tr>
<!-- Repeat the above cells many more times -->
</table>
</div>
```

I don't know if it's meant to do this, but I don't want it to because it just leaves a bunch of blank page below it, is there something I can do?

**EDIT:** I figured out the problem is caused by a date picker javascript widget that I have within the table. Code updated and here is the link to the widget: [DatePicker](https://github.com/freqdec/datePicker).
I tried to create a fiddle with all of this, but it kept freezing up and the script stopped running. Is this normal when there is a script running inside the `<div>` like this?

**EDIT:** To clarify, what I want is to have a `<div>` with the viewing area limited to 400px high and to get rid of the extra blank space below it. When I remove the `Javascript` datepicker widget, everything works as it should, but for some reason the `Javascript` is causing the webpage height accommodate the hidden content of the `<div>`.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but I can't reproduce your result. Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Are you putting your table content in table cells and not the actual <table> tag? http://jsfiddle.net/vzmvg/

Comment: Damn it. I can't get it to reproduce on jsfiddle either!

Comment: @Calvin yes, the content is being placed inside of cells and not just between the <table> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the problem has been solved...by the datepicker developer, Brian McAllister. In the CSS of the datepicker there is a class set for the `:link` and `:visited`, here is a snippet:

```
.date-picker-control:link,.date-picker-control:visited {
display:-moz-inline-stack;
}
```

When the display is changed to:

```
.date-picker-control:link,.date-picker-control:visited {
display:-moz-inline-box;
}
```

The problem goes away. Thanks Brian!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to change the overflow to "hidden"?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I haven't tried that because that would defeat the purpose. I want to be able to view the content, but just limit the viewing area to 400px high.

Comment: in that case - try "overflow-y: auto" this would show the scrollbar only if it's needed (is this what you want)?

Comment: I've clarified my question.

Comment: I understand now. Try debugging with e.g. firebug, what's creating this extra space and if this doesn't help - I would change the datepicker (it's not the best practice to mix js in html like this).

Comment: How would you recommend to accomplish this using best practice?

Comment: create only containers in html (with classes or ids) and then - in a separate js file - attach datepicker to these containers. Have a look at the sample code here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker

Comment: very interesting. How would I make that work with many (read: 100's) of date fields all with different id's?

Comment: if you use a jquery plugin (or jquery ui datepicker) this is just 1 line: assuming all your containers have class="date-field", you can just write: $('.date-field').datepicker({ /*options*/ });

Answer (score 0):

Its having vertical scrollbar because you have asked for y-scrollbar.
try sumthing like

```
#wrapper {width:1227px; height:400px; overflow:auto;}
```

css & html is sufficient enough to handle an overflow.

Comment: EDIT: To clarify, what I want is to have a <div> with the viewing area limited to 400px high and to get rid of the extra blank space below it. When I remove the Javascript datepicker widget, everything works as it should, but for some reason the Javascript is causing the webpage height accommodate the hidden content of the <div>.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `overflow-y` to `auto` will show a scrollbar only when it is needed:

```
#wrapper { /* ... */ overflow-y: auto; }
```

Comment: EDIT: To clarify, what I want is to have a <div> with the viewing area limited to 400px high and to get rid of the extra blank space below it. When I remove the Javascript datepicker widget, everything works as it should, but for some reason the Javascript is causing the webpage height accommodate the hidden content of the <div>.